# Phone get hanged while unzipping a file in android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, file, unzip

I am trying to unzip a .zip file in android phone.The below code is working fine.

```
public static void unzip(File zipFile, File targetDirectory) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile)));
    try {
        ZipEntry ze;
        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            File file = new File(targetDirectory, ze.getName());
            File dir = ze.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();
            if (!dir.isDirectory() && !dir.mkdirs())
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to ensure directory: " +
                        dir.getAbsolutePath());
            if (ze.isDirectory())
                continue;
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            try {
                while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
            } finally {
                fout.close();
            }

            /* if time should be restored as well
            long time = ze.getTime();
            if (time > 0)
                file.setLastModified(time);
            */
        }
    } finally {
        zis.close();
    }

}
```

When i call this method with arguments it unzipped the file successfully but the problem is that file size is 55MB and before calling this method app is working good but when i call this method, the few seconds about 8-13 seconds that app takes to unzip the file the app got stuck, nothing is working but after successfully unzipped the file, the app again working good so please help me so that app should work during unzipping the file.
I also tried to execute the method in

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

});

but not get success.

Comment: Your code suffers from the unzip problems cited by CERT in [this advisory](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/IDS04-J.+Safely+extract+files+from+ZipInputStream). In addition to using a background thread as seen in the first answer below, consider validating to make sure that you are not unzipping files outside of `targetDirectory` and are more immune to zip bombs and similar attacks. My CWAC-Security library has a `ZipUtils` class with an `unzip()` method that addresses these attacks: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/#usage-ziputils

Answer (score 3):

If the app freezes it's usually because you do too much computation on the main/UI thread (note that `runOnUiThread()` does exactly this). To avoid that you have to call your method in another thread or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

A quick and dirty fix would be using a plain thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        unzip(zipFile, targetDirectory);
    }
}).start();
```

Or with an AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask<File, Void, Void>() {
     protected Void doInBackground(File... files) {
         unzip(files[0], files[1]);
         return null;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         // we're finished
     }
}.execute(zipFile, targetDirectory);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.
I have used "AsyncTask" and its working great but a new problem is come to face that if i run app without using "AsyncTask", on app exit "System.Exit(0)" my app closed successfully but when i use "AsyncTask", after exiting app using "System.Exit(0)", app restarts again and the same method called written in "doInBackground" of "AsyncTask". So please help me that how i can resolve this issue so that app closed completely.